# Converting registry access to db calls from MFC Feature Pack

Tags: c++, database, mfc, registry, mfc-feature-pack

We may start converting an old VS2003 MFC project to use the fancy new features provided by the MFC Feature Pack and VS2008. Several of the new UI controls would be very nice except for one thing - they automatically save their information to the registry. I don't have a problem with the registry, but for the multiple environments the users use out program from, it's much easier to save user data to the database.

So, I'm hoping that there is one main "access the registry" function that could be overloaded to point the database. But brief investigation hasn't turned up anything. Has anyone else had any success doing something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it should be possible to do what you're suggesting, according to the information on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309001.aspx) in MSDN. I haven't tried this myself, so I don't know how difficult it will be in practice.

According to the documentation, you should create a class that inherits [`CSettingsStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982141.aspx) to read and write the settings, and call [`CSettingsStoreSP::SetRuntimeClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309027.aspx) so that the framework uses your class instead of the default.

Answer (score 0):

The MFC feature pack uses code supplied by BCGSoft and they added this feature (so you can save state to an XML file, database, etc.) way back in 2001.  I don't have the feature pack on this PC but try looking for a class called something like `CMFCRegistrySP`.

I will check myself tomorrow.

Does the `StateCollection` sample do this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983406.aspx