# Adding drop down arrows to CMFCToolBar buttons

Tags: mfc, drop-down-menu, mfc-feature-pack

Can anyone explain how to add dropdown arrows to CMFCToolBar toolbar buttons - like for undo/redo buttons.  We had this with CToolBar by using the TBSTYLE_EX_DRAWDDARROWS style and TBN_DROPDOWN notification.  This doesn't seem to work with CMFCToolBar.  These dropdown arrows i believe are added to the VisualStudioDemo MFC feature pack demo but i can not figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

In the VisualStudioDemo sample, in `CMainFrame::OnToolbarReset` they replace the Undo button of the toolbar with a custom class called CUndoButton, like this:

```
m_wndToolBar.ReplaceButton(ID_EDIT_UNDO, CUndoButton(ID_EDIT_UNDO, _T("&Undo")));
```

`CUndoButton` is declared in file `"UndoBar.h"` of the sample project, so you can use it or change it however you like.

Comment: That's what i was starting to think.  But then if i comment out the ReplaceButton call and rebuild the application shouldn't the dropdown arrow go away?  I'm finding that it does not.

Comment: That's because the feature pack samples store their window/toolbar settings in the registry. The same occurs for me but if I delete this registry key then the dropdown arrow goes away: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MFC\Samples\VisualStudioDemo

Comment: See this question for more info about the new MFC registry storage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184253/converting-registry-access-to-db-calls-from-mfc-feature-pack

Comment: No worries. By the way if you would like to accept this as your answer please tick the green tick on the left. Cheers.